# create style in Android for marquee effect on all TextViews

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I want the Marquee effect on EVERY textview in my app...so I thought I put it in a style:

```
<style name="MyTextViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-thin</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
</style>
```

and set it in the app theme:

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
<item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyTextViewStyle</item>
</style>
```

this doe **not** work :(

Tried it directly on the TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:textAllCaps="true" />
```

This **does** work...

With the following condition: **the style may NOT have the 'focusable' and 'focusableInTouchMode' options.**
But without these uptions in the TextView example above, it will not scroll...

so I need these attributes, but am unable to get them to work via styles...anyone have an answer?

Comment: Give yourtextview.setSelected(true); to your textview in activty. hope it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **focusable** and **focusableInTouchMode** not working in Style then remove from **Style.xml** and add in every `TextView`

```
<style name="MyTextViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-thin</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
</style>



<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
<item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyTextViewStyle</item>
</style>
```

In Your `layout.xml` file.

```
<TextView
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
    android:textAllCaps="true" />
```

**Note : this will work if there is only one `TextView` in layout..**

If you have many TextView as marquee in single layout then look at this example, [Android-MarqueeView.](https://github.com/ened/Android-MarqueeView)

Comment: Thanks, I did not know you cannot have more than one TextView marquee...! pointing me to a custom view will probably lead to a solution for me

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `android:ellipsize` is not a text style element, so it is not inherited with `android:textViewStyle`.

Just add your `MyTextViewStyle` as a style to a `TextView` to check my guess. If this is the problem, you have to add the `android:ellipsize` attribute individually or in a style.

Comment: Nope, I was not able to fix it by adding the style to the TextView directly...I am actually trying to add it to a style, but it just doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
<TextView
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:id="@+id/text_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:textAllCaps="true" />
```

and marquee effect will work only if text length is bigger than scree width.

Comment: I know this works, but it just doesn't work with a style. I do not want to need to add it to every textview manually